# Kal.h no such file or directory error

Tags: iphone, calendar, static-libraries, static-linking, icalendar

I know questions related to Kal Calendar has been asked multiple times in Stackoverflow.

But i am stuck badly. Please share your views on this. So...

I have followed all instructions in https://github.com/klazuka/Kal but as soon as i run my app it says Kal.h no such file or directory error.

I think i am doing wrong in header search path. But i am adding relative path from my project's directory to the "Kal/src" directory.

On double click to header search path I **check mark on recursive** and then adding **"/Volumes/Development/Imp/Astro 4Feb /klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/src"** in the path field.

What's wrong in it ?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at their example. They use ../../src and I don't see $(SRCROOT) there, so I guess they are not pointing the header search path as they said in the readme file. You may just point the header path where you have placed their source (Kal/src) and make it relative your project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set root directory. Make it relative to your project.